# Find the leftmost (most significant digits) of a large exponent calculation, say $99^{99}$

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponentiation

I want to find the initial 10 digits of an exponent calculation whose result is a very large number - 
Say, $99^{99} = 3.697296 \times 10^{197}$

I only need to know the digits $3697296$

Is there any way of finding this without doing the full calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use common logarithms and a decent calculator. Using a fairly mediocre one on your example, I get $99\log_{10}99\approx197.5678842652$; subtracting $197$ and raising $10$ to the resulting power, I get $3.697296376497$, so the number must be about $3.697296376497\times10^{197}$.

**Added:** More generally, for $a^b$ calculate $b\log_{10}a$, subtract the integer part, and raise $10$ to the resulting power. If $n=\lfloor b\log_{10}a\rfloor$, the integer part of $b\log_{10}a$, your number is

$$10^{b\log_{10}a-n}\times 10^n\;,$$

and you’ll be able to read of the most significant digits from the lefthand end of $10^{b\log_{10}a-n}$.

Comment: This is great, but I need a generic method for even larger numbers. Edited the question, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: As he says, take the log10 of the (lower) 1234.  Multiply by the (upper)1234.  Subtract the integer - that will be the exponent.  Raise 10 to what you have left, and you get a number between 1 and 10.  Then multiply by 10 to the power of that integer.

Comment: @NitinNain: The method works fine even on substantially larger numbers, provided that you have a calculator with enough precision. The one [here](http://www.ttmath.org/online_calculator) easily handles your $1234^{1234}$ example.

Comment: Yes, got it now. Thanks.

Comment: @NitinNain: You’re welcome.